# Windows Cmd - How to delete all but a given file type

Tags: c#, windows, command-line, cmd, command-prompt

I am looking for something like this:

```
  Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C del path\*.(filetypetobedeleted)");
```

but instead I want to delete all but one type of file type (.txt). This includes folders in the path, so I want everything in the path to be deleted but .txt files.

Comment: You could do something with GetFiles, and drop all the .txt files and then delete whats left.

Comment: Why use *cmd* for this? You can easily use `Directory.GetFiles`

Comment: You can copy the ones you want to keep to a temporary folder, then delete all the others, then copy back..

Comment: If you *have* to use a batch, use Powershell and specify an `-Exclude` filter, eg `del c:\scripts\* -exclude *.wav`

Comment: @CosmicLuna If your problem is solved, make sure you mark as accepted the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 2):

.NET has built-in types for working with directories and files. It's easier to use these classes than starting a separate process just to execute `del`.

You could write something like:

```
var skipExtension=".some";
var directory=new DirectoryInfo(myTargetPath);
var filesToKill=directory.EnumerateFiles()
                         .Where(fi=>fi.Extension!=skipExtension);
foreach(var file in filesToKill)
{
    file.Delete();
}
```

[EnumerateFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratefiles(v=vs.110).aspx) has overloads that allow searching for specific patterns and searching all subdirectories, eg:

```
EnumerateFiles("*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

If you absolutely *have* to use batch processing, use PowerShell, not cmd. You can create and execute a PowerShell pipeline directly from C#, by using the [PowerShell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell(v=vs.85).aspx) class.

`del` is a synonym for [Remove-Item](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176938.aspx)  in PowerShell which contains an `-Exclude` parameter. If you want to exclude a specific extension, you can write:

```
Remove-Item c:\scripts\*.* -Exclude *.wav
```

or

```
del c:\scripts\*.* -Exclude *.wav
```

To execute this command from a C# program, you need to create a PowerShell instance and add the command and parameters:

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddCommand("Remove-Item")
  .AddParameter("Path",@"h:\test\*.*")
  .AddParameter("Exclude","*.svc");
var results=ps.Invoke();
```

If you want to delete folders as well, you need to add the `-Recurse` parameter

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddCommand("Remove-Item")
  .AddParameter("Path",@"h:\test\*")
  .AddParameter("Exclude","*.svc")
  .AddParameter("Recurse");
var results=ps.Invoke();
```

Comment: `foreach (var dir in directory.EnumerateDirectories()) dir.Delete(true);` should also delete directories recursively.

Comment: @JuanFerrer that would delete everything, including the files the OP wants to preserve. You could delete the files first, then delete empty directories by checking `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles().Any()` for each folder, or create a recursive method that deleted the files of each folder first, then deleted the folder itself if it was empty

Comment: Well, the OP didn't say anything about the files **in** the folders. I'm assuming the desired files are being moved out of the folders before deletion. Otherwise, folders will remain if they contain a file matching the specified pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
// Set as read-only
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C attrib +r " + path + "\\*." + ext);

// Del will skip read-only
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C del " + path + "/q *");

// Rm folders recursively
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C for /d %i in (" + path + "\\*) do rd /s /q \"%i\"");

// Remove read-only
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C attrib -r " + path + "\\*." + ext);
```

You probably want to give it a second to do its thing. As mentioned by @TheLethalCoder, you can `proc.WaitForExit()`if using a single `Process` instance.

**Edit**: This gets ugly very quickly. You should be using.NET for this. Or even Power-Shell as explained by @PanagiotisKanavos.

Comment: Instead of an arbitrary sleep you could `WaitForExit` or start `cmd` with multiple commands.

Comment: That's even better. I'll add it to the answer then.

Comment: Does this work for folders in the path? I tried this and it almost worked, but it failed to delete folders.

Comment: @CosmicLuna you didn't ask for *folders*.

Comment: Del only works on files. If you want to delete folders as well, you should use .NET methods.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos From original post: " This includes folders in the path, so I want everything in the path to be deleted but .txt files."

Comment: @CosmicLuna that doesn't mean "delete the folders". You used `del`, a command that handles *files*, with a pattern that can match only *files with extensions*. You *can* do what you ask with PowerShell's `del` and a simple `-Exclude` parameter

Comment: @CosmicLuna Check the third command. It loops through the path, finds every folder and removes it recursively. But bear in mind that .NET makes the whole thing far simpler.